# Angular - binding data into a form?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms

I'm a bit baffled by Angular. I'm trying to alter a form by giving the fields values from $scope.data but although I know I can "see" the data, I can't get it to display.

When I press on an item on a list I use this to get the data:

```
ng-click="openModal(data)"
```

This opens the modal with the form in it and passes the data to the openModal function. I know it's working because there is a pop-up called in the openModal function that says "You are accessing data:" and then the id of the row, or the title or whatever.

Now what I want is to use the data to alter the view, the form. I want this:

```
 <input type="text" placeholder="Namegoeshere" value="{{$scope.data.nameOfRecord}}">
```

All I get in the input field is the text [object.Object] though.

I know the full record is being passed because

```
console.log("The data is: ", data);
```

gives me the full record I can inspect in the console.

Why can I not get access to the data in the form?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use

```
 <input type="text" placeholder="Namegoeshere" ng-model="data.nameOfRecord">
```

instead

```
 <input type="text" placeholder="Namegoeshere" value="{{$scope.data.nameOfRecord}}">
```

Comment: This is the one. Thanks! I knew it was something simple like this.

Answer (score 1):

Remove $scope from the view(HTML) because {{}} brackets already two way bind scope model with view:-
Use:-

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Namegoeshere" value="{{data.nameOfRecord}}">
```

Comment: I tried that. The answer above was the correct one. Thank you for your input though.